# Renaming a column that R recognizes as a function

Tags: r

I have a large data set with set column names, I need to rename the columns. Here are the columns:

```
class(spec_sub_act_feat_all)
[1] "data.frame"
names(spec_sub_act_feat_all[,82:86])
[1] "angle(tBodyAccMean,gravity)"          "angle(tBodyAccJerkMean),gravityMean)"
[3] "angle(tBodyGyroMean,gravityMean)"     "angle(tBodyGyroJerkMean,gravityMean)"
[5] "angle(X,gravityMean)"
class(names(spec_sub_act_feat_all[,82:88]))
[1] "character"
```

However, when I try to rename the columns using

```
names(spec_sub_act_feat_all) <- gsub(`angle(tBodyAccMean,gravity)`,
'Vector of mean body accelerometer signal',names(spec_sub_act_feat_all))
Error in gsub(`angle(tBodyAccMean,gravity)`, "Vector of mean body accelerometer signal",  : 
  object 'angle(tBodyAccMean,gravity)' not found
```

or simply

```
names(spec_sub_act_feat_all[,82])<-"Vector of mean body accelerometer signal"
```

Neither one works. I believe my problem is that R is recognizing the column name as an actual function and won't let me select the character string to change it. The first renaming I tried with gsub(), I used `` to try to select the column name as not a function, which was recommended in another post, but did not work for me. I did notice that I could substitute out what was in the () but not the whole 'angle(...)' part.

Comment: You may need to escape the `(` and `)` with `\\(` or use `fixed.= TRUE`

Comment: Using the fixed=TRUE argument in the gsub() worked! Thank you akrun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `(` and `)` are metacharacters to capture the group in regex mode, if we use this in `gsub`, the default option is `fixed = FALSE` i.e. regex mode, either we need to escape (`\\(`) or place it in square brackets (`[(]`) to literally evaluate it in regex mode or we can specify `fixed = TRUE`

```
gsub("angle(tBodyAccMean,gravity)",
    'Vector of mean body accelerometer signal',
                     names(spec_sub_act_feat_all), fixed = TRUE)
```